# Sort a list based on another list followed by a property on itself with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting, dictionary

The following dictionary represents the key/value pair of a destination city ID and the number of filters associated to that city:

```
Dictionary<int, int> totalCityFilters
```

This dictionary is sorted by descending number of filters and it's the way I need it to be. I then have an unsorted list of flights:

```
List<Flight> unsortedFlights
```

Each `Flight` object has a bunch of properties where the most relevant to my problem are `DestinationID` and `FinalPrice`. I need to create a new list of flights where they are sorted based on the following 2 premisses:

1. The list should first be sorted based on the order of `totalCityFilters`, the key on that dictionary matches the property `DestinationID`. The flights list might have multiple flights with the same `DestinationID` (this is not the primary key).
2. The list should then be sorted (ascending) by the `FinalPrice` property.

**However, the second sort must not destroy the first one.** I mean, a cheaper flight (A) must not be on top of a more expensive flight (B) if `B.DestinationID` appears first than `A.DestinationID` on `totalCityFilters`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If i have understood you correctly:

```
var result = unsortedFlights
             .OrderByDescending(f => totalCityFilters[f.DestinationID])
             .ThenBy( f => f.FinalPrice)
             .ToList();
```

If the value of `totalCityFilters` is the number you want to order by first.

Comment: Yes, that's it, so simple, thanks... I was expecting something big and confusing. I didn't know we could sort accessing the dictionary like that (all examples I could find used joins) and I wasn't really aware of the existence of the `ThenBy` method. I edited your answer to reflect the descending order I wanted though :)